# Где можно найти видео по парсингу сложно сайта python?

Tags: python

Искал видео по парсингу сложных сайтов по типу eldorado где помимо всяких headers надо работать и с куками и т.д, на русском сегменте не нашел парсинг нормального сайта, может есть на англ язычном ютубе пример парсинг таких сайтов, не могу перейти порог уровня до которого дошел и не могу перешагнуть

Comment: Попробуйте искать не видео

Comment: Видео было бы намного понятнее, а так кому как. По мне больше видео по душе

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Можно к примеру у Олега Шпагина посмотреть, сам его смотрю...
Тоесть у него есть видео об парсинге web и нетолько...
Если надо ссылка на канал то вот -> https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCfxnN0xALQR6OtznIj35ypQ/playlists
А вообще я тоже щас эту тему рассматривал, но ответов маловато...
Можно посмотреть например как поотдельности все парсить, это как вариант
надеюсь немного помог...